# str.insert() doesn't work

Tags: c++, string, insert

I'm trying to search the string and insert a double quote.  I'm searching a string for a delimiter and trying to insert "\"" before or after the delimiter (doesn't matter).

Program compiles, but it freezes when it reaches this function.It doesn't give me any errors while compiling.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
string text="This|is|the|text";
string Quote="|";


void Insert()
{
  size_t i=0;
  string insert="\"";

  while ((i = text.find(Quote, i)) !=string::npos) 

{
    text.insert(i,insert);    
    }
 }
```

Comment: No, `str.insert()` works. Your code doesn't. Always assume that the errors are in your code rather than in the standard library.

Comment: I didn't mean, there's an error in STL, I meant my code with str.insert doesn't properly work.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what's happening here.  You find a `'|'` at position `i`, then insert a character at position `i`, then continue searching from position `i`.  Where is the very next `'|'` now?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that in cases like this, it's usually better to create a new instance of the string, copy and modifying as you go, than to try to modify the string in place.  In idiomatic C++, you'd be using iterators, which might be invalidated by any insertions, and even with indexes, it can be extremely complicated to keep the index where it belongs when you're inserting or deleting.